# bash history for current session

Tags: bash, command-history

Maybe I'm overlooking something but is there a way to get your current bash history for the current session you are using like

if i run

```
ssh host
$ pwd
$ ls
$ cd /tmp
```

I just want to see those 3 commands and nothing else

Comment: have you checked `history` command??

Comment: ya i know about `history` but that doesn't give just my session

Comment: The amount saved between sessions is controlled by the SAVEHIST shell variable if I recall.  Thus if the amount of history you saved last time was ZERO, then you'd get history for the current shell session (but of course not at the sub levels)

Comment: @mdpc, what docs are you reading?  In the Bash man page I find no reference to SAVEHIST but only to `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A slightly roundabout way:

```
history -a ~/current_history
```

This will save the current session's unsaved bash history to `~/current_history`, which you can then view.

Comment: this could work but doesn't handle multiple sessions.. I supposed i can create a random temp file to store it in

Comment: @Mike use a name connected with the shell PID, perhaps `~/$$_history`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't clear out the history or affect the normal history saving in any way! I wasn't sure until I tested it. :)

Comment: I find it more convenient to just do `history -a` it throws it along with the previous history into ~/.bash_history ... which could be a problem if your history is longer than the cutoff, which is a 1000 on my centos7 and fedora 24 systems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem that I wanted to write the current `history` to a *file* but still wanted the entries to be recorded in the main bash `history`

I solved this by just attaching the *file* with `cat`:

```
history -a current-history
cat current-history >> .bash_history
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `history -a` with a filename. This can be a device-file, like `/dev/stdout`.

Then you can pipe that however you like. For example, to view your current session history in `less` you can

```bsh
history -a /dev/stdout | less
```

Comment: Piping to less works, but you could just as well pipe to cat.

Comment: sure, but in less you can search, yank, execute etc. the main point was you can pipe it

Comment: you can do an interactive prompt `history -a /dev/stdout | vipe | bash`

Comment: I'm a fan of less (use it a lot), but perhaps the answer should mention that it can be piped, for example less?

Comment: @DannyStaple don't you mean you use it `more`? Fair point. Edited.

Comment: +1 for the pun... indeed.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one which received the tick, but 7yrs  too late.

Comment: @XTian Stackexchange, the perfect place to find stale advice <3

Answer (score 1):

Use `comp` to compare the entire history (incl. current Bash session) with the already persisted history in `.bash_history` and only print those lines that are unique to the current session -- which should show only those commands that were executed since starting the current Bash shell

```
comm -23 <( history | cut -c 8- ) ~/.bash_history
```

**Edit:** as @Wildcard pointed out this command does not work for all distributions of `comm`. I tested this on Mac OS.

A variation of the same idea using `diff`:

```
diff <( history | cut -c 8- ) ~/.bash_history | sed -n 's/^< //pg'
```

Comment: A good thought, but very unreliable in my tests.  [`comm` assumes sorted input.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html)  But, welcome to Stack Exchange!  :)

Comment: @Wildcard, both sides of the input to `comm` are sorted inherently in my example above. **Did you run it?** And it did not produce your current Bash session history?

Comment: Yes, I did, and no, it didn't.  And no, the contents of `~/.bash_history` is *not* sorted; and nor is the output of `history` sorted at all once leading line numbers are removed.  (Besides which, `comm` expects lexicographically sorted input, not numerically sorted input.)

Comment: Right, I meant both arguments to the `comm` command in my example are in the same order, not that they are sorted lexicographical. The FreeBSD version of `comm` does not require lexicographically sorted input

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X.  It has nothing to do with that.  Looking closer, it appears to be the *early* commands from the in-memory history, which have since been overwritten in the history *file* by other shells exiting.

Comment: @Wildcard I added a variation of the same basic idea using `diff` and `sed` which does not require lexicographically sorted input and other Bash sessions exiting in the meantime should not impact the results unless the other Bash sessions ran identical commands

Comment: Still no.  Consider: 500 commands in history file.  I open shell (session) A, run 10 commands.  (Commands 11–510 appear in output of `history`.)  I open session B, run 30 commands, close shell.  History file is updated.  Now it includes what were originally commands 31-500, plus the 30 commands run in session B.  In shell A, the command you give (including the diff commands) will show commands 11-30 (which are not from the current session), followed by the 10 commands from the current session.  (cont'd)

Comment: In the exact circumstances I describe, `history | sed '1,/^  500  /d;s/.......//'` will work, but if more than 500 commands have been run in the current session it just won't print anything, and it's overly tied (tightly coupled) to the values of `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTSIZE`.  I think [`history -a ~/$$_history`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171348/135943) is really the only way to go here.

Comment: But...I hope you stick around here on this site!  :)  It's a clever approach, and the edge cases are very much non-obvious; it took me some fiddling and exploring to see why it didn't work.  (I have lots of Terminal sessions going on my Mac independently, so it was pretty obvious at a glance that it was including stuff it shouldn't be.  Finding out why was a lot harder.)