# Is there a way to tell how many commands I've run since I ssh'd / logged in, in bash?

Tags: bash, command-history

I run the `history` command in bash but it gives me everything...

I noticed that I'm able to limit the number of previous commands displayed by running `history | tail -n <num-of-lines+1>`; so is there some way to see only what I've run since I logged in using the number of commands I've run since I logged in in bash?

Comment: You can adapt the answer from the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171341/bash-history-for-current-session) like this: `history -a /dev/stdout | wc -l`. Notice that it assumes that you're **NOT** using something like `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"`

Answer (score 5):

If you just want a general count without specifics, try `echo $LINENO`.

The interpreter treats your session as a stream, and counts the lines coming in. That's *basically* how many times you have hit the return.

If you type multiline commands, each line will be counted separately.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  There is no built-in way I believe but you can define a
new variable and increment it after every command.  For example:

```
$ count=0
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='count=$((count + 1))'
$ echo $count
1
$ echo command
command
$ echo another command
another command
$ echo $count
4
```

**EDIT**:

Or knowing that history is stored in memory until shell exits
something like that would also do the job providing that you didn't
modify history format or use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to save history after
each command:

```
diff <(history | sed -E 's,\s+?[0-9]+  ,,') ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: That will work only in certain circumstances. What if other session overwrites `~/.bash_history` during current session?

Comment: It wouldn't work then. But the first method could still work: `history | tail -n $count` providing that history would not be overwritten with `history -r` for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in command. You can cheat a little bit, but result depends on your setup. Closest thing I can think of is:

```
history | tail -n `history | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \\\$1-$HISTSIZE;}"`
```

You can alias it.

Command `history` enumerates it's entries. Most of time your `$HISTFILE` has maximum entries (`$HISTSIZE` value). So you will find that extra commands numbered above `$HISTSIZE` as list of commands typed in this very ssh session.

It works by showing history with numbers, than getting last line of it and first column and substracting `$HISTSIZE` value, so we know how many commands were after we log on. This parameter is sent to tail -n which shows only that number of last entries from history.

Unfortunately it does not work properly when there are less than `$HISTSIZE` commands in history. To make it better you will need to do some extra setup in your `.bashrc` file, so whenever you are logging in there is extra variable set up which remembers number of entries in history. Then use that variable instead of `$HISTSIZE`

Answer (score 0):

For a per-session count, I would use HISTCMD. It tracks across all of bash's saved history, though, so save a copy of the incoming HISTCMD for this shell instance and then subtract against it.

In `~.bashrc`:

```
OHISTCMD=$HISTCMD
```

and then any time you want to know the count,

```
echo $((HISTCMD - OHISTCMD - 1))
```

Noting from the manual:

> If HISTCMD is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

and also that recalling commands from history with up-arrow does not increment HISTCMD.

It's just too bad that the [global variable `history_offset`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/history.c#n88) isn't available externally!